# How to remove duplicate Images obtained from Twitter Rest Search API?

Tags: python, image, twython, twitter-rest-api

I am using twython to extract images shared on twitter for #apple. The images have a unique image ID assigned by twitter but the images are pictorially same. How can I detect duplicate images ?

For Local Images, I got the solution:

Calcuate Hash for every image and then remove the duplicates.

```
import struct
import os
import hashlib

def jpeg(fh):
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    assert fh.read(2) == "\xff\xd8"
    while True:
        marker,length = struct.unpack(">2H", fh.read(4))
        assert marker & 0xff00 == 0xff00
        if marker == 0xFFDA: # Start of stream
            hash.update(fh.read())
            break
        else:
            fh.seek(length-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    print "Hash: %r" % hash.digest()
jpeg(file("two.jpg")) # Gives the hash of the image
```

However, twitter images are stored on external server and this approach is not working ? Let say I have to obtain only unique images from twitter?

for example: twitter data gives:

http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CKwk2doVEAE-Y9g.jpg
http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CKwka9fUwAEmdLr.jpg

and all three are same images.

Comment: You'll have to do the same thing with the remote images.  You'll have to grab them via the requests library and perform the same sort of operation you are doing above.

Comment: i think you have to download the images. you can delete them after doing the process. but i am eager to see if someone comes up with a solution.